# unable to have jdbc connection in jsp file

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jdbc, ubuntu

hey all i am trying to have simple jdbc connection in my jsp file the file is as under:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%><html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
hello world.
<% 

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/saurabh","root","");
    System.out.println("Connection successful");
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

%>
</body>
</html>
```

whenever i try to run this code i get following console output in eclipse:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.apache.jsp.myJspDemo_jsp._jspService(myJspDemo_jsp.java:68)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

one last thing when i tried to have the same kind of connection from a simple java file then this was working. so what's the problem with jsp file.

PS: I am working on Ubuntu 10.10 distro and with Eclipse 3.5. And i have also added the jar file to the java build path of Project. And this is working just fine on windows.

So what to do??

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Very bad idea to get connection in the JSP.

Comment: You should put code only in `.java` files and presentation only in `.jsp` files. Mixing them leads to maintenance nightmares later on.

Comment: @user: no business logic should reside in JSPs. They should be used **only** to produce output. Any business logic (including DB connections) should be done in Servlets/Actions (depending on your use of any web frameworks). Or better yet: in dedicated classes that are called from Servlets/Actions.

Comment: the problem is that JSP should be only the view layer, and should not contain any business logic.

Comment: link about MVC:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller
Also you should check this out:
http://www.springsource.org/

Comment: There are many problems associated with this approach. One of them is code repetition. Any web project usually contains lots of JSPs. If you copy/paste this code on all of them, this will become a problem when you will need to make any change (for example, your server address, database name, password etc).

Comment: hey all fine i won't be going for this approach but now can you all please pay attention on the problem please.

Answer (score 3):

You need to deploy the mysql driver to your servlet container (Tomcat / Jetty ) so that the JSPs can find them.

But as @crafstman said in the comment, it is very bad practice to put DB related stuff in the display code. Be it for security reasons, be it for performance.

Comment: I am new to jsp's and servlets so can you please elaborate this. still thanks for you response

Comment: Since adding the JDBC driver to the webapp would be necessary even if the logic is extracted from the JSP, the first line is still applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Your mysql driver JAR should be placed in `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your project before you deploy it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `MySQL driver` to `tomcat/lib` or You can put the MySQL driver to `yourapplicationproject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`

Putting the database connection into `jsp`is not good practice.
I will be better if you put the database connection in to `Servlet code`